# GSON Generic: failed to deserialized json object

Tags: android, json, rest, deserialization, gson

I'm programing a rest service. Object I try to reply is a generic:

```
public class ResultadoBaseJsonForm<ID extends Serializable,E> implements Serializable{

private String resultado;
private String mensaje;
private List<ObjectError> errores;
private Map<String,String> erroresValidacion;
private ID id;
private E obtjetoTransporte;
```

And the object implemented is:

```
ResultadoBaseJsonForm<Long,List<Reference>>
```

On client side the code is:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ResultadoBaseJsonForm<Long, List<Reference>>>(){}.getType();
ResultadoBaseJsonForm<Long, List<Reference>> objectResponse =   gson.fromJson(jsonresult, collectionType);
```

The message is:

```
{"resultado":"OK","mensaje":"Referencias consultadas correctamente","errores":null,"erroresValidacion":null,"id":null,"obtjetoTransporte":[{"code":"140.12","type":"1","family":"1","tittle":"1","descripcion":"1","drawable":"","drawableSmall":""},"code":"140.6","type":"1","family":"1","tittle":"1","descripcion":"1","drawable":"","drawableSmall":""}]}
```

And I get this error:

```
The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@a7415fb0 failed to deserialized json object 
[{"code":"140.12","type":"1","family":"1","tittle":"1","descripcion":"1","drawable":"","drawableSmall":""},{"code":"140.6","type":"1","family":"1","tittle":"1","descripcion":"1","drawable":"","drawableSmall":""}] given the type java.util.List<com.six.tma.bean.Reference>
```

Reference class is:

```
public class Reference implements Serializable, Cloneable {
@DatabaseField(id = true) 
private String code;

@DatabaseField(canBeNull=false)
private String family;
@DatabaseField
private String tittle;
@DatabaseField(canBeNull=false)
private String type;
@DatabaseField
private String descripcion;
@DatabaseField
private String promotion;
@DatabaseField
private String mechanic;
@DatabaseField
private String period;
@DatabaseField
private String quota;

@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
private byte[] drawable;
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
private byte[] drawableSmall;
```

Any help?

---

Sorry I attached the a wrong JSON:

```
{"resultado":"OK","mensaje":"Referencias consultadas correctamente","errores":null,"erroresValidacion":null,"id":null,"obtjetoTransporte":[{"code":"140.12","type":"1","family":"1","tittle":"1","descripcion":"1","drawable":"","drawableSmall":""},{"code":"140.6","type":"1","family":"1","tittle":"1","descripcion":"1","drawable":"","drawableSmall":""}]}
```

I tested it on  jsonlint.org click and it is valid. I gerenrate it on spring.

Any help?

Comment: insert your code at http://jsonlint.org/ click validate, and look at the error, your json is invalid (you have name-value pairs within an array instead of having them wrapped in an object)

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is wrong, I do not know how you generate it on server side but you are missing a `[` before the second "code" token.

If you have a server coded in Java, you could use Gson also to serialize your response.

As suggested in comments, you can take advantage of checking your JSON with a service like http://json.parser.online.fr/ to check your JSON when parsing errors occur.